# ajax pagination using datatable plugin

Tags: php, datatables, jquery-pagination

I am trying to use datatable plugin for ajax pagination. It loads the first set of data but the pagination doesn't work.
Can someone Please give me a good example of datatable ajax pagination?

I need to know how to set the number of rows to display as well.

Comment: post your code here.I need what have you tried so far..

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an AJAX end point (database will populate table from here).

Following JSON data is expected from datatables.

```
iTotalRecords – Number of total records in the table, before applying the filters.
iTotalDisplayRecords – Number of records returned after applying the filters.
sEcho – An un-altered copy of the sEcho sent from the client.
aaData – Array of data from the server.
```

Please read it here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/working-jquery-datatables/